# streamlit error in AttributeError: 'OneHotEncoder' object has no attribute '_infrequent_enabled'

Tags: python, machine-learning, model

Traceback:
File "C:\Users\spand\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 565, in _run_script
exec(code, module.**dict**)
File "C:\Users\spand\Desktop\laptop price prediction\app.py", line 68, in 
st.title(int(np.exp(pipe.predict(query))))
File "C:\Users\spand\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py", line 457, in predict
Xt = transform.transform(Xt)
File "C:\Users\spand\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sklearn\compose_column_transformer.py", line 763, in transform
Xs = self._fit_transform(
File "C:\Users\spand\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sklearn\compose_column_transformer.py", line 621, in _fit_transform
return Parallel(n_jobs=self.n_jobs)(
File "C:\Users\spand\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 1085, in **call**
if self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
File "C:\Users\spand\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 901, in dispatch_one_batch
self._dispatch(tasks)
File "C:\Users\spand\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 819, in _dispatch
job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
File "C:\Users\spand\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\joblib_parallel_backends.py", line 208, in apply_async
result = ImmediateResult(func)
File "C:\Users\spand\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\joblib_parallel_backends.py", line 597, in **init**
self.results = batch()
File "C:\Users\spand\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 288, in **call**
return [func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\spand\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 288, in 
return [func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\spand\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\fixes.py", line 117, in **call**
return self.function(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\spand\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py", line 853, in _transform_one
res = transformer.transform(X)
File "C:\Users\spand\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing_encoders.py", line 888, in transform
self._map_infrequent_categories(X_int, X_mask)
File "C:\Users\spand\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing_encoders.py", line 726, in _map_infrequent_categories
if not self._infrequent_enabled:

How to overcome this problem no i can't find the reason behind it

Answer (score 0):

Please check the version of streamlit (update the sklearn version)

```
ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('col_tnf',OneHotEncoder(sparse=False,drop='first'),0,1,3,8,11])],remainder='passthrough')
```

Answer (score 0):

Came here because I ran into this same problem with both OneHotEncoder and OrdinalEncoder on streamlit.

Specifying sklearn version in the requirements.txt file fixed the problem (i.e. making sure sklearn version matches the version used to train the model)